# How to make a list of buttons listen to event from a different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with a variable number of "slave" buttons that should listen to when the "master" button was clicked.  See image below:

[image: Buttons on webpage]

I would like to wire up the events using jQuery so that when the "master" button is clicked, a JavaScript function is called for each of my "slave" buttons.  I want each individual "slave" button to listen to events fired by the "master" button.  Each "slave" button has the class attribute set to `class="btn btn-default slaveButton"` where I can use the class "slaveButton" to get all of the "slave" buttons using jQuery's class selector.  Since the number of "slave" buttons is variable, I'm not sure how to set this up in JavaScript and an example would be nice.

Each "slave" button has an HTML5 data attribute on it with its index in the list (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4) that I will pass into an ajax request.

Comment: In the master button's click handler, have each slave perform something:`$('.masterButton').click(function(){
 $('.slaveButton').each(function(index){
  console.log(this);
 }) 
})
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you already know how to do it.

```
//wire up event listener for master button
$("#master-button").click(function() {
    //your master button was clicked.
    //loop over all the slave buttons
    $(".slaveButton").each(function( index, btnElement) {
        //index shows the place of the slaveButton in the list/dom
        console.log("your button element is", this, "and was triggered when" , $("#master-button").get(0) , "was clicked);
    });
});
```

Comment: I do know how to do it...in other languages.  JS is a tool I sometimes have to work with.